# Multiple or Single ListViews in Android Activity

Tags: android, listview

Would it be better to have 3 seperate ListViews in an Activity and hide 2 or re-cycle 1 Listview from a performance and resource stand point?

Comment: I believe having only 1 Listview would be better, because you will hold only resources for 1 Listview and only its resources. In the other hand, you will be holding 3 lists with each resources.